# Available NetBeans tools for JavaServer Faces (JSF/Facelet) support

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, plugins, facelets

Which [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) plug-ins or tools would you recommend for [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) development?

Comment: Would depend on what Frameworks you may or may not be using, what sort of web apps you are making and several other things. You mentioned Facelets as a tag, are you using any other frameworks? More Info Plz. :)

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "NetBeans" :)

As far as I know, NetBeans offers a [native support](http://www.netbeans.org/features/web/web-app.html) of JSF development. So, I don't think you need additional plugin, no?